# how to mov from eax to lower register like ax and bx

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

does my code works this way because I worried to move to a lower register with a mistake.(the error is: Error   2   error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size D:\assembly project\assemblyproject\assemblyproject\assembly1.asm   25  1   assemblyproject
)

```
.data 
message1 BYTE "enter the 1st number",0dh,0ah,0
message2 BYTE "enter the 2nd number ",0dh,0ah,0
message3 BYTE "the GCD is: ",0dh,0ah,0
nb1 dword ?
nb2 dword ?
.code
main proc

mov edx, offset message1        
call writeString
call ReadDec
mov nb1,eax
mov edx,offset message2
call ReadDec
mov nb2,eax
mov ax, nb1
mov bx, nb2

calculate_GCD:
    cmp ax,bx
    je display_gcd
    jb swap_nb
    div bx
    cmp dx,0
    je display_gcd
    mov ax,bx
    mov bx,dx
    jmp calculate_GCD

swap_nb:
    XCHG ax,bx
    jmp calculate_GCD


display_gcd:
    movzx eax, dx
    mov edx, offset message3
    call writestring
    call writedec

invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: [Assembler Programming - Moving content of 32 bit register to a 16 bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21664348) shows you that you can just `mov bx, ax`, because AX is the low 16 bits of EAX.  But your code block is never moving between registers, only to memory and back.  What width do you want `nb1`  and `nb2` to have?  And why do you have memory variables at all instead of just using registers?  Is that only because you were trying to work around `mov reg,reg`?

Comment: Also note that Irvine32 functions like WriteDec take a whole register as input, so usually you'd want to `movzx ebx, ax` or something like that, to copy the low 16 bits of EAX to BX but also zero the high 16 bits of EBX instead of merging with whatever garbage was there in the high half.

Comment: i will show you my whole code